# Impact of changing swappiness

Tags: linux, mysql-5.7, ubuntu, aws

On one of my aws ec2 m4.10xlarge instance running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with 160 GB memory, I want to change the swappiness from the default 60 to 10. Does changing this at runtime using

sysctl -w vm.swappniess=10

have any negative impact when executing this command?

I have a production MySQL 5.7 database running on this instance. So while changing the swappiness will there be any micro stalls or any other issues which I should be considering? Is it safe to run this when the database is busy or does it need to be run only during off-hours? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am neither a kernel developer nor a MySQL author, but...  If you were going the other direction, you might see an increase in disk activity as the kernel began to more aggressively swap inactive process pages to disk in order to grab the space for disk caching, but since you're merely advising the kernel that it doesn't need to be as aggressive about reserving memory for cache, you shouldn't see any immediate impact. It's not going to start pulling pages out of swap just because it can; it'll leave what's already there there until they're actually needed, and just be less aggressive about writing new pages out. (Likewise, MySQL isn't going to suddenly panic and make major adjustments as it sees free RAM slowly being reduced because of the decreased swap usage.) This what my understanding of the mechanisms tells me should happen, and my experience (amounting to no more than a dozen incidents) seems to agree.